# PipedOutput/InputStream upload to sftp using spring integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'd like to stream data in couple of goes to the sftp server. I'm using spring boot integration. I've setted up SftpRemoteFileTemplate like this

```
  @Autowired private SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory;

  @Bean
  public SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate() {
    final SftpRemoteFileTemplate template = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory);

    template.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(
            new LiteralExpression(contactSenderSftpProperties.getSftpSessionProperties().getBaseSftpPath()));

    template.setTemporaryFileSuffix(".tmp");

    return template;
  }
```

but my destination file is not appended instead overwritten by the latest contents of temporary file I'm sending data to.

My writer looks like this

```
  public void write(List<? extends Item> items) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Write {}", items);

    final int timeoutSeconds = 60;

    try (PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream()) {
      log.debug("Preparing to write...");
      final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

      writerClient.write(items, pipedInputStream, countDownLatch);

      if (!countDownLatch.await(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        throw new TimeoutException("Operation stream not connected");
      }

      sftpRemoteFileTemplate.send(
              MessageBuilder.withPayload(pipedInputStream).setHeader(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "contacts.csv").build());

    }
  }
```

where method WriterClient#write

```
  @Async("writerThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
  public void write(List<? extends Item> items, PipedInputStream pipedInputStream, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) throws IOException {
    try(final PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInputStream)){
      countDownLatch.countDown();
      csvSerializer.serialize(pipedOutputStream, items.stream());
    }
  }
```

and writerThreadPoolTaskExecutor

```
  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor writerThreadPoolTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorBuilder taskExecutorBuilder) {
    return taskExecutorBuilder
            .corePoolSize(properties.getWriterThreadPoolCorePoolSize())
            .maxPoolSize(properties.getWriterThreadPoolMaxPoolSize())
            .queueCapacity(properties.getWriterThreadPoolQueueCapacity())
            .threadNamePrefix("writer-task-thread")
            .build();
  }
```

In nutshell I'd like to write many small temporary files and merge them to one containing all the data. I'm not really sure about PipedInput/OutputStream. Is it possible to append PipedOutputStream many times and upload PipedInputStream only once to sftp when there is no more data to write ? But then question arises how do I know if all the date was written ?

Comment: sftp does have append functionality so it should be theoretically possible

Comment: Yes, it does but is not allowed to append temporary files.

Comment: I could create one file on the beginning, append to it and then move it destination directory.

Comment: Yes; and the `RemoteFileTemplate` has an `append()` method.

Comment: I've decided not to use temporary file name functionality. My solution is write (with each call append) file to temporary directory on sftp server. When there's no more data to upload move file to destination directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into an SFTP Outbound Channel Adapter and its `APPEND` mode: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#spel-and-the-sftp-outbound-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Use the `append()` method on the `RemoteFileTemplate`.

```java
    /**
     * Send a file to a remote server, based on information in a message, appending.
     *
     * @param message The message.
     * @return The remote path, or null if no local file was found.
     * @since 4.1
     */
    String append(Message<?> message);
```

The implementation looks like this

```java
    @Override
    public String append(Message<?> message, String subDirectory) {
        return send(message, subDirectory, FileExistsMode.APPEND);
    }
```